# WordPress при клике на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" нужно что бы пользователь оставался на странице

Tags: wordpress

Проблема описана в видео https://disk.yandex.ru/i/--39oBeTyI5ScA

Сайт на WordPress. Есть ли ваши варианты решения данной проблемы ?
Может можно js код накидать

Сам сайт: акустический-поролон.рф

Comment: Неужели в распиареной коммерческой теме  (The7) нет такой элементной возможности? Ну тогда можно использовать любой понравившийся плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/ajax+cart+woocommerce/